# jQuery selector behaviour in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

Anyone know why:

```
var strId = "xyz";
var oSectionOuter = $( "div#myr-body" ).find( "div#" + strId );
```

works in IE7 (actually IE8 with "Compatibility Mode") with the HTML below, but this doesn't?:

```
var strId = "xyz";
var oSectionOuter = $( "div#" + strId );
```

According to Microsoft's "excellent" Javascript debugger, oSectionOuter ends up being a reference to the whole DOM object rather than any particular node within it.

```
<html>
<body>
...
<div id="myr-body">
...
<div id="xyz">
...
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `id="xyz"` elements in your page?

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I checked, and, no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from the HTML posted.

**If the HTML looks like this:**

```
<html> 
<body>
   <div id="myr-body"></div>
   <div id="xyz"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Then the problem is:**

```
$("div#myr-body").find("div#xyz");
```

This selector says, "find the div whose id is equal to 'xyz' but exists within the div named 'myr-body'."  This will NEVER resolve.

**For the problematic selector to work the HTML would HAVE to look like:**

> ```
> <html> 
> <body>
>    <div id="myr-body">
>       <div id="xyz"></div>
>    </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Otherwise, you might have multiples.